# How to detect multiple selections in elFinder

Tags: javascript, elfinder

I added a new toolbar button and an new context menu item to elFinder.

Works nicely but this item should be enabled only if *one plain file* is selected. So should be dimmed when no file selected and should be dimmed when multiple files are selected or if is selected an directory.

I learned than in the `elFinder.prototype.commands.mycmd` I should set the `this.getstate` return value to:

- `0` if the toolbar/context-menu item should be enabled and
- `-1` if it should be disabled

So, now have this:

el

```
Finder.prototype.commands.mycmd= function() {

    var self  = this,
        fm    = self.fm;

    self.disableOnSearch = true;

    self.title = 'mycmd';

    self.getstate = function() {
            // need help here to add the "directory is selected check"
        return fm.selected().length == 1 ? 0 : -1;
    }

    self.exec = function() {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, i know only Perl, so it is a bit hard for me digging thru all elFinder's javascript code to figure out how to master the condition.

Know anybody `elFinder` enough deeply to help me with the condition?

Answer (score 2):

Just find the solution in the elFinder's `download.js`.

This works - at least for now.. ;)

```
elFinder.prototype.commands.mycmd= function() {

    var self  = this,
        fm    = self.fm;

    self.disableOnSearch = true;
    filter = function(hashes) {
        return $.map(self.files(hashes), function(f) { return f.mime == 'directory' ? null : f });
    };

    self.title = 'mycmd';

    self.getstate = function() {
        var sel = self.fm.selected(),
        cnt = sel.length;
        return  !self._disabled && cnt == 1 && cnt == filter(sel).length ? 0 : -1;
    }

    self.exec = function() {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```